# Return updated struct from its methods for testing?

Tags: struct, rust, functional-programming, mocking

I'm trying to do some TDD with rust and I have to add a simple abstraction to make
the code agnostic for multiple "backends". The backends need an init function for setup (they perform a connection to an external system),
but I'm not sure how to test all of this. I thought about doing it in a functional way,
with a trait Backend with the init function so a struct that implements it
returns a new version of itself initialized.

```
#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
pub trait Backend: Sized {
    fn init(&self) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>>;
}
```

Using the `mockall` crate to test with mocks I could mock a Backend and test that the init function is called where it needs to be called.

I'm not sure if this is a good practice in rust. In functional languages it's the norm to return updated versions of some object. Here with rust I'm wondering if it's not ideal and how could I test something like this with another approach.

If for example I'd move out the init function, then I'd have to have an enum for the possible backends to pattern match against and perform the different inits based on the kind of backend? I'm not sure it's a better solution.

I'm still learning rust and testing so I'd appreciate any help in designing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why return Self when you may just update it in-place?

```rust
pub trait Backend {
    fn init(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
}
```

However, it is preferred not to have objects in non-initialized state at all and statically ensure that object is always initialized. If you have to instantiate it somewhere instead of passing it from outside, use builder:

```rust
pub trait BackendBuilder {
    type Backend;
    fn build() -> Result<Backend, Box<dyn Error>>
}

pub trait Backend {
  // Always initialized
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I went to check out the builder pattern in rust, it seems very useful and appropriate for my case. Regarding writing unit tests using the builder pattern, I think I could still use a mocked Backend with its relative backend builder, I'll experiment with that for now.

Comment: You probably mean `Self::Backend` in `Result`, not `Backend` (since the latter is equal to `dyn Backend`)?